# Markdown to NSAttributedString library?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, markdown, nsattributedstring

Now that NSAttributedString is fully supported in iOS 6, is there a library that will take an NSString with markdown, and convert it to NSAttributedString?

Answer (score 11):

I've just added an `NSString` to `NSAttributedString` lightweight markup parser to [MGBoxKit](https://github.com/sobri909/MGBoxKit). It's not Markdown but it's very similar. So far it supports bold, italics, underline, monospacing, text colour, background colour, and kerning.

The [MGMushParser](https://github.com/sobri909/MGMushParser) class is now a standalone pod, so can easily be used independent of MGBoxKit.

```c
NSString *markup = @"**bold**, //italics//, __underlining__, `monospacing`, and {#0000FF|text colour}";

UIFont *baseFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
UIColor *textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

myLabel.attributedString = [MGMushParser attributedStringFromMush:markup
                               font:baseFont color:textColor];
```

Comment: Thanks! Something like this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: This looks to be it's new home:
https://github.com/sobri909/MGMushParser

Comment: Thanks @danfordham. I've edited the reply to use the correct link now.

Answer (score 6):

I just open-sourced a project that takes raw markdown and converts it into an NSAttributedString:

https://github.com/dreamwieber/AttributedMarkdown

It's a work-in-progress and includes a demo application which shows how to assign attributes to the various markdown elements.

Comment: Very interesting. Is there also a function for doing the opposite: NSAttributedString to Markdown String?

Comment: Thanks. Not at this time, but it is certainly something that could be added.

Answer (score 1):

[DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) converts html to NSAttributedString, also [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) have some basic markdown support.

Comment: Just a note if you need high performance do not use DTCoreText for HTML, it's still really inefficient for rendering/parsing. Use Bypass (ObjC) or Cocoa Markdown (swift)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, since this was the first post I found, you can now use [NSAttributedString initWithData & NSDocumentTypeDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688-CH1-SW33) to parse simple html on iOS 7

It seems easy enough to use a Markdown parser to HTML, then initWithData to do the rest. See http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2013/09/29/easy-markdown-rendering-with-nsattributedstring-on-ios-7.

For the HTML conversion, see my answer in [ios7 font size change when create nsattributedstring from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992950/ios7-font-size-change-when-create-nsattributedstring-from-html/24817891#24817891)

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at https://github.com/xing/XNGMarkdownParser, works fast and reliably

Comment: This seemed like a great option, but links when formatted for markdown, did not work.

Comment: [Reference-style links that is.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Bypass](http://uncodin.github.io/bypass/) is a good alternative which is also frequently updated (unlike most other repos mentioned). It even provides a custom `UIView` subclass which takes care of the rendering itself. It also uses Core Text directly instead of a UITextView, which should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling a lot to fine full-Markdown library that it's easy to use and finally I found [CocoaMarkdown](https://github.com/indragiek/CocoaMarkdown).

It's really great, supports most of the syntax and have easy to use API. The only thing that was missing was image support, so I forked it and add full-image support, along with cacheing and enabling to use images wrapped in URLs, hope it will solve the problem I had for someone else:

https://github.com/X8/CocoaMarkdown