# How to Display data Coming From Json in Html Format (Bold, Font, Italic, UnderLine)?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview

My data is coming From Server with Html Tags.

I want to display it on my Text View as it's format (Bold, Font, etc). How can i display it?

`Thanks in Advance`

Comment: NSAttributedString ? What's your issue exactly? Extracting the html string? Rendering it?

Comment: please share your code snippet what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Web View For this. Create one object and load that string to web view.
 [_webView loadHTMLString:[strDescription description] baseURL:nil]; // set string to web view

For increase Dynamic Height of Web View:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGRect frame = _webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    _webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [_webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    _webView.frame = frame;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
    _bgScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, fittingSize.height+370);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *infoString =@"I am iOS developer.";

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];

    UIFont *font_regular=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f];
    UIFont *font_bold=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:20.0f];

    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_regular range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font_bold range:NSMakeRange(5, 18)];

    [self.txtView setAttributedText:attString];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992950/ios7-font-size-change-when-create-nsattributedstring-from-html