# HTML formatting in UILabel (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I found this code

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: (text?.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)
```

This returns an attributed string. But the font become too small and different than the one I want. How could I set a default font for that String?

Comment: Either your enumerate the NSFontAttributeName and change it, or you add a new HTML tag to change it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992950/ios7-font-size-change-when-create-nsattributedstring-from-html

Answer (score 2):

Just tried something different and I solved:

I did something like that:

```
text = "<font color=\"black\" face=\"arial\" size=\"15\">" + text + "</font>"
```

And then used the code above.

Hope that will be useful for someone